# Self Hosted (console) WCF configuration

Tags: rest, wcf

i had a WCF server running through a Console application, it will run as an azure service so i don't to host it in ISS.

I belived it work well and share datas to my web app through ajax request. But when i maked a service that recieve a filestream, i realized that my binding configuration is not used at all. My WCF work same without binding section.

My probleme concerne especially the key "maxReceivedMessageSize" because default value limit me to 8Ko request and it is a problem for uploading file.

Bindings section (that i can comment) :

```
<webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MyBindingConfig" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Buffered">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
```

Services section :

```
<service name="MyData.Service.MyDataServiceRestFull">
    <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding"
              contract="MyData.Service.IMyDataServiceRestFull" bindingName="MyBindingConfig" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:9997/MyDataServer"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
```

Note that i tryed with basicHttpBinding and i had same issue.

Comment: Shouldn't your transferMode be Streaming? Have a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: i tryed "Streamed" but, as i said in my post, all modifications i try in binding section changed nothing

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're incorrectly referring to your binding in your `<endpoint/>` element. You're using the `bindingName` attribute, when you should be using the `bindingConfiguration` attribute:

```
<endpoint binding="webHttpBinding"
          contract="MyData.Service.IMyDataServiceRestFull"
          bindingConfiguration="MyBindingConfig" />
```

Comment: thanks for response, i tryed it but WCF still answer HTTP 413 error (Request Entity Too Large) with 16Ko file...

Comment: Enable tracing on the server, so you know exactly which quota is being exceeded...

Comment: <ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: Le quota de taille maximale autorisée pour les messages entrants (**65536**) a été dépassé. Pour augmenter le quota, utilisez la propriété MaxReceivedMessageSize sur l'élément de la liaison appropriée.</ExceptionString>

Comment: Are you sure the `name` attribute in your `<service/>` element is correct? It could be that the thing is completely being ignored because it doesn't match the right service class name....